# Number of edits

Tags: feature-request, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I see how many posts have I edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91878/where-can-i-see-how-many-posts-have-i-edited)

Is there a way to see how many edits I've made? In other words: I'd like to see how close I am to getting the `Strunk & White` badge.

Comment: Status-by-design

Comment: In other news, you've made at least 35 edits, but the total number will forever remain anonymous.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's possible we will make an exception for edits, since we view editing as so crucial and fundamental to how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: Does that mean we will be seeing number of edits in our profile soon?

Comment: What is the status?

Comment: can we able to see how many edits i have made?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [data dump](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) to see how much entries was last edited by you with this query:

```
select count(*) from posts where LastEditorUserId = <id>
```

It will less than the real number and has the actuality of the first day of the month.

Answer (score 4):

There's a [Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/240/how-many-edits-until-strunk-white) for that.  Unfortunately, the data is not completely current.  But, it gives you a better platform for estimating.

Comment: -1 It is showing me -43 for userid: 379693

Comment: @PareshMayani This means you already have the badge!

Answer (score 0):

Jeff has stated that the badge system was designed around the xBox-live badge system. And it is intentional that you don't know when you're about to receive a badge, it simply shows up unexpectedly. So currently, at least through the SO engine, there is no way to know how many edits you have made.

Comment: Sorry, but I selfishly prefer Jeff's answer  :)  Also I've never played xBox so I was unaware that badges are a surprise in it.