# Where can I see how many posts have I edited?

Tags: support, edits, data-explorer

I've found [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) many queries to check edit counts, and I get different results for each one. Which one is the most accurate and up-to-date query? Or is there any way to see the edit count in stats?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Yes, there certainly is a place where you can check this:

1. Click on the ["Users" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users) in the main navigation bar.
2. Click on the ["editors" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors).
3. Select the ["all" filter](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all).
4. Search for your user name.

When you see your account listed, look at the fourth line, which will tell you the total number of posts that you have edited. For example, mine shows that I've edited 3,465 posts on Stack Overflow:

[image]

I would have checked the stats for your account, but I see that you haven't associated your account here on Meta with your account on Stack Overflow.

However, do note that the number reported here is showing *all* of your edits, including those made to your own posts and multiple edits to the *same* post. It is therefore not a very good measure of one's eligibility for badges such as Strunk & White or Copy Editor, but it does provide a general idea.

Comment: is there any way for somone who is not in the league table to see this information?

Answer (score 21):

I have found if you go to one of the review pages, you can hover over the bar next to <kbd>stats</kbd>, for example

[**stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/stats**](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/stats)

[image: edit]

You can also access this page directly

[**stackoverflow.com/review/badge-progress/first-posts**](https://stackoverflow.com/review/badge-progress/first-posts)

Comment: the `Editors` tab in Users shows your edits and `retag`  only edits while the edit count in `stats` only count the edits not the `retags` only see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81655/what-kind-of-edits-are-counted-in-userstab-editors

Answer (score 1):

Another way to access the `Badge Progress` popup pictured in @StevenPenny's answer is available even to users who don't have a review link to click yet (for lack of reputation) without entering the URL manually (which also works without review privileges). Assuming you've suggested at least one edit:

1. Visit your profile.
2. Click the `activity` tab.
3. Click the `suggestions` tab within/below the `activity` tab.
4. Click any `suggested edit` link that's available (not the link to the question, but to your edit)
5. Hover over the bar next to `stats` as pictured in [Steven Penny's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164282/246931). It's the same one, but on a slightly different page to which anyone can navigate just by clicking through these steps.