# Is there some hidden statistics page on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support

For example if I wish to track how many posts have I edited.

Comment: Not really hidden unless you mean you can't find it

Comment: Yep, it's pretty tricky to find, it'd be nice if they had a section in the User Profile where all the edit/review badge progression stats could be found.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91880/190533

Comment: @woz, the answer there doesn't give the real stats in relation to the needed amounts for editing badges

Answer (score 1):

They're not *supposed* to be hidden; you can find various numbers regarding your actions on your user page, for instance [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/485337/adam-arold?tab=activity&sort=revisions).

Of course, there's all sorts of information that isn't directly exposed anywhere. For these, you can dig in with the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

An easy way that I use is:

1. Click on the review link at the top of the page https://stackoverflow.com/review
2. Click on one of the tasks, for example, close votes https://stackoverflow.com/review/close
3. Hover over the bar to the left of stats, and Copy Editor exists to show you how many edits you have (as well as a couple others).

[image]