# Why are number of edits reported in Profile and Users Tab different?

Tags: support, edits

I have seen the following question which is about what edits contributes towards badges:

- [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges)

Also these questions which talk about where I can see how many posts I have edited:

- [Where can I see how many posts have I edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91878/where-can-i-see-how-many-posts-have-i-edited)
- http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6162/how-can-i-find-out-how-many-edits-ive-made

However, why do the number of edits reported in my Profile (see point 3 below) and the number of edits reported in Users Tab (see point 1 below) differ?

<sub>All the images are for [my profile on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users/114818/aditya).</sub>

1. As per [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91880/205516), in Users Tab → Editors Tab → all filter → it's 592:

   [image: users>editors]
2. As per [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164282/205516), the one's which count towards badges, it's 509 (no problem, this is clear why it's different):

   [image: badges]
3. As per [this answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6177/114818), in my Profile → Activity → Revisions → it's 616:

   [image: revisions]
4. As per [this answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6163/114818), this data-query shows it as 739 (completely contrary to what the comment on that answer says):

   [image: data-query]

Why are these numbers different — specially the ones mentioned in points 1 and 3?

Comment: BTW the data explorer is updated weekly (no live data).

Comment: @juergend: Yes, I know - it should be lagging in numbers. However, it shows the maximum count - this is why I have included it, otherwise I wouldn't have :)

Comment: Hmm, in /users I'm 1,451; I've got the same in the badge progress, which is what I'd expect. I think these two numbers should be identical and are the number of posts you've edited that are not yours/wikis etc. I have 1,738 revisions in total, which includes my own posts which I've edited, which is kind of depressing. It means I've edited over 50% of my posts post posting...

Comment: I bet the counts are for deleted versus still-available posts.

Comment: It seems unlikely that I've never edited a deleted post whereas someone who's just got 2k rep has edited 83 @Martijn. Unless the Ask Ubuntu community really like deletions... though I guess I could now be eligible to see deleted posts so my numbers have become the same. Let's check meta...

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: Yeah, the guess was wrong. But I have a better answer below.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: Difference between /users and badge progress is because of [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/445/205516).

Comment: Yes Aditya, that's pretty much my guess. I think @Martijn's got it with his answer as I've just realised my review thing has 1,294.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The first count (592) includes edits to your own posts, and only counts specific types of edits (excluding title and tag-only edits for example).

  <sub><sup>(To verify, I made a (justifiable) edit to an older post of mine and my count rose by 1. Making another (justifiable) edit to a post I already edited this week and the count rose. I then removed a useless tag name from a question title, and the editors-tab count did *not* change. Similarly, edits that only add or remove tags do not increase the count either).</sup></sub>
- The Data explorer query you used counts *unique edits*; editing a post twice counts as two edits. The badge counts edits to *unique posts*, where two edits to one post count as one edit for the badge.

  To get unique posts instead, query for `COUNT(DISTINCT PostId)`.
- For the copy editor badge, a series of types of edits are excluded, prominently edits to your own posts.

Comment: It looks like users may be unique edits to non-deleted posts (below 10k) and all posts (10k +) that are not owned by you... *sigh*

Comment: @Aditya: trying to figure that out next.

Comment: @Aditya: Unique posts versus repeat edits explains the difference.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: So, this means that point 1 includes any number of edits we make to our own posts (if we edit our post 100 times - it's count would rise by 100). However, if we edit someone else's post for 100 times, it would only count it as once. However, Revision Activity tab would increase the count for both of them by 100. Is this what you are saying?

Comment: And regarding data-query, I don't know how to edit them. Can you please fork the query and provide a link to it. Thanks!!

Comment: @Aditya: No, that's not what I am saying. I am saying that the first count only counts unique posts that you edited.

Comment: @Aditya: There is a `fork query` right there. Create an account on the data explorer and you can do it yourself! :-)

Comment: What is the meaning of 'unique posts` - do you mean revisions? Regarding data query, do i need to edit just 1st line of the actual code? I actually don't know SQL and its commands :)

Comment: @Aditya: The first line, yes, so instead of `where count(id)` is replaced with `where count(distinct postid)`.

Comment: Ah with repeat edits you mean: if we edit our own question/answer - it doesn't count as repeat post. However, if we edit someone else's question/answer consecutively (say thrice), then /users would count them as 1 and revision activity would count them as 3. Is this what you mean? However, if we edit someone else's post once > then a 3rd user edits the post > and then we edit it again. Both the counts would increase by 2. I know it's complicated :)

Comment: @Aditya: Actually I am wrong about the tab count being for unique posts. Verifying the actual counts now.

Comment: @Aditya: Multiple edits per post do count separately, but edits to just the title (and possibly just the tags) do not count.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: are you sure about that? If yes, I would accept it. Otherwise, I would wait for SE staff/moderators to clear the confusion. However, I highly doubt that it doesn't count titles.

Comment: @Aditya: Just editing a title is a separate PostHistoryTypeId in the database, actually, so it's not so surprising. I just had another opportunity to edit *just* the title, and again the count did not go up. So yes, I am sure. :-)

Comment: You mean it did not go up for both point 1 and point 3 - right?

Comment: @Aditya: The edit count in my activity tab goes up for a title-only edit (your point 3). The edit count in the editors list does not go up (your point 1).

Comment: Okay... That clears the confusion.. :) However, I think I would wait 1-2 days more to see if it attracts the eyeballs of SE staff/mods. A confirmation from them would be wonderful. If not, I would accept your answer... Thanks :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Do you think it could be a bug? Shall this question be tagged as [tag:bug]?

Comment: @Aditya: No, I don't necessarily think that that is a bug, no.